# Image zoom on hover with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

I'm trying to do this guide: [Link to Guide](https://stanhub.com/how-to-create-zoom-effect-on-image-hover-with-css-and-jquery/) and I cant get that end :S, my image doesn't zoom out when I hover the image :S

The result should be something like this: [Result](https://stanhub.com/tutorials/hover-to-zoom-image-effect/)

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<body>

<div id="logo">
    <img src="img/logotipo.png" alt="logotipo" id="logotipo" class="img-responsive" />
</div>

<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <p class="navbar-brand">JVasconcelos</i>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="#" title="Return to the Homepage">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Visit the Features Page">Features</a>    </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="See the prices">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Learn more about our organization">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Contact us!">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="col-md-4" id="img1">
            <img src="img/img01.png" alt="img01" class="img-responsive img-zoom" id="img01">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.img-zoom').hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass('transition');

            }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('transition');
            });
    });
</script>                           

<script src="js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
```

CSS:

```
/* Navbar styling */

.navbar { background: #ddd; margin-top: 200px; border-radius: 0; }
.navbar ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.navbar li a { float: right; line-height: 80px; padding: 0 30px; text-decoration: none; color: #555; }
.navbar li a:hover { background-color: #aaa; color: #333; }
.navbar-brand { margin-left: 40px; margin-top: 15px; }

/* Logotipo */

#logo { width: 300px; height: 300px; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -150px; margin-top: -350px; }

/* COL-MD-12 */

.col-md-12 { height: 450px; background-color: #fff; text-align: center; margin-top: -20px; padding-top: 45px; }

/* COL-MD-4 */

#img1 { height: 150px; width: 150px; background-color: #333; text-align: center; color: #fff; margin-left: 20px; }
#img01 { height: 150px; width: 150px; border-radius: 1px; border-spacing: 2px; border-color: #0000000; }

/* HOVER */

.img-zoom { width: 350px; -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.transition { -webkit-transform: scale(2);  -moz-transform: scale(2); -o-transform: scale(2); transform: scale(2); }
```

When I set up this code, I get the image possitioned where I want it, but when I hover the image, it doesn't work, and nothing happens :S
What I'm doing wrong guys? Sorry for this long post :S

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are doing this with jQuery instead of pure css? Also can you look in the devtools to see if the element actually gets the class set on it?

Comment: Its the tutorial I found of what effect I want :S I didn't found how to do it on pure css and I'm so newbie coding :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the [demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/dxtp4zzh/2/). You can add all the browser prefixes to it.

**Updated:**

```
    <div id="img1">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1458668383970-8ddd3927deed?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=1e9d6264da3ae9cacdddcad3b63f3c04" alt="" class="img-zoom">
    </div>


.img1 {
  margin: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

#img1:hover .img-zoom {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

.img-zoom {
  width: 100%;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

Comment: if I set this, all my containers get moved:
    .container { margin: 100px; width: 300px; height: auto; }
    .container:hover .image { cursor: pointer; transform: scale(1.3); }

Comment: @JoseAntonio I'm sorry I used bootstrap specific classes, let me adjust

Comment: @Dejan.S You still can, you just need to correct your ``transform`` property. It currently says ``scale(1)`` not ``scale(1.1)`` or ``2.2``, ``3.3`` and so on.

Comment: @JoshCrowe Not sure I follow you there. The `scale(1)` is on the image in its original state, basically it has no effect.

Comment: ``.img-zoom:hover { transform: scale(1.2); }``

Comment: @JoshCrowe got it, yea of cause that approach can be done, and should be done. I'm actually not sure why I did the container hover, mainly because I seen the container had an id :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with Pure CSS, which is far more simple and can be put with the rest of your CSS you've already written.

You utilize this:

```
.the-object-you-want-to-zoom:hover {
  transform: scale(2.2);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/